# How to show RuntimeException on JSP

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I throw a `RuntimeException` with a message and I want to show it on JSP

```
.....
String ip = getClientIP();
if (loginAttemptService.isBlocked(ip)) {
     throw new RuntimeException("blocked");
}
.....
```

I tried `<c:out value="${RuntimeException}"/>`, but it was a wrong approach. How can I show the message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in different ways. As I assuming your requirement, you want to show the Exception message as an validation error in your jsp page. In that case, I would prefer not to throw an `RuntimeException`, rather I would bind the Error message to `HttpServletRequest` object from the invoking `HttpServlet` you are dealing with.

Then it would be able to access that message from your jsp and can show that as you like -

in your Servlet

```
String ip = getClientIP();
if (loginAttemptService.isBlocked(ip)) {
     request.setAttribute("error", "blocked");
}
```

Now in your jsp, just do this

```
<c:if test=${error not empty}/>
   <c:out value="${error}"/>
</C:if>
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked like a charm. Since I was using `choose, when, otherwise` I just wrote test as `<c:when test="${not empty error }">`

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own `error.jsp` in a different file:

```
<%@ page isErrorPage="true" import="java.io.*" contentType="text/plain"%>
<%=exception.getMessage()%>
<c:out value="${exception}"/>
```

Just add it to the `web.xml` like this:

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.RuntimeException</exception-type>
    <location>/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Comment: Is it possible to show the error without redirecting to error.jsp?

Answer (score 0):

```
<%

         int x = 0;

         if (x ==o ) {
            //some logic
         } 
         else
{
throw new RuntimeException("message");
}

      %>
```

Can you try something like above